# Running Python locally on Mountain Lion

Tags: python, macos, apache, permissions, localhost

I have my local environment set up to run MySQL and PHP. I'm beginning to branch into other languages and trying to get Java, Python, and Ruby to run in my local web server.  All of the languages are installed correctly but apache is not recognizing them or giving me permission issues.

I've started with Python and after many issues getting apache to recognize the .mod I am now getting a 403 error when I go to that page.

I'm not sure what the next step is in trying to get this to work correctly.

403 Forbidden

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
          DocumentRoot "/Library/Webserver/Documents/python-mn"
          ServerName python.local
          ServerAlias www.python.local
          WSGIScriptAlias / /Library/WebServer/Documents/python-mn/wsgi.py
          <Directory /Library/Webserver/Documents/python-mn>
                #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
          </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Checked the Apache error Log:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log
[Fri Sep 06 15:30:51 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_hfs_apple: Mis-cased URI or unacceptable Unicode in URI: /Library/WebServer/Documents/python-mn/wsgi.py, wants: /Library/Webserver/Documents/python-mn/
```

Ping the local environment:

```
ping python.local
PING python.local (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.041 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.153 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.159 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.130 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.134 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.073 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.135 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=0.111 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=0.130 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=0.131 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=0.133 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=13 ttl=64 time=0.136 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=14 ttl=64 time=0.132 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=15 ttl=64 time=0.140 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=16 ttl=64 time=0.136 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=17 ttl=64 time=0.105 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=18 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=19 ttl=64 time=0.074 ms
```

MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013), OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.4)

---edit---

wsgi.py file:

```
import bottle
import os

def application(environ, start_response):
    data = "Hello World!"
    start_response("200 OK", [
            ("Content-Type", "text/plain"),
            ("Content-Length", str(len(data)))
            ])
    return iter([data])
```

---edit 9/9/13 11:46am ---

**New error now:**

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, you@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

**apache error log**

```
[Mon Sep 09 11:43:08 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Sep 09 11:43:08 2013] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Micheles-MacBook.local for ServerName
[Mon Sep 09 11:43:08 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.6.1.
[Mon Sep 09 11:43:08 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.6.7.
[Mon Sep 09 11:43:08 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Sep 09 11:43:08 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Mon Sep 09 11:43:08 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.6.7 PHP/5.5.3 mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8x DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Sep 09 11:43:18 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=7888): Target WSGI script '/Library/WebServer/Documents/python-mn/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Sep 09 11:43:18 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=7888): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/Library/WebServer/Documents/python-mn/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Sep 09 11:43:18 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Sep 09 11:43:18 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Library/WebServer/Documents/python-mn/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
[Mon Sep 09 11:43:18 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     import bottle
[Mon Sep 09 11:43:18 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: No module named bottle
[Mon Sep 09 11:43:18 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=7888): Target WSGI script '/Library/WebServer/Documents/python-mn/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Sep 09 11:43:18 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=7888): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/Library/WebServer/Documents/python-mn/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Sep 09 11:43:18 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Sep 09 11:43:18 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Library/WebServer/Documents/python-mn/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
[Mon Sep 09 11:43:18 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     import bottle
[Mon Sep 09 11:43:18 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: No module named bottle
```

This is what I am expecting to get, its the same file structure and code as my AppFog install: http://python-mn.aws.af.cm/

---edit 9/9/13 1:03pm---

I did a terminal command to install bottle... not sure how to make sure the wsgi.py or vhosts knows where to located it. Apparently the AppFog server had that natively and thats why I didn't need anything extra to make it run.

```
easy_install -U bottle
Searching for bottle
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/bottle/
Best match: bottle 0.11.6
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/b/bottle/bottle-            0.11.6.tar.gz#md5=0bafdc4e13ea2b1a3bddf36b5af108c4
Processing bottle-0.11.6.tar.gz
Writing /var/folders/hc/dtnjvkvn1dd931bkkxty_05w0000gn/T/easy_install-QS4GZM/bottle-0.11.6/setup.cfg
Running bottle-0.11.6/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/hc/dtnjvkvn1dd931bkkxty_05w0000gn/T/easy_install-QS4GZM/bottle-0.11.6/egg-dist-    tmp-pQrFpa
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
bottle: module references __file__
bottle: module references __path__
Adding bottle 0.11.6 to easy-install.pth file
Installing bottle.py script to /usr/local/bin

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bottle-0.11.6-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for bottle
Finished processing dependencies for bottle
```

Comment: Could you include your wsgi.py file?  I'm specifically curious if you don't have a #!<path to python interpreter> at top.

Comment: @Foon Its a "Hello World" script. It works on my AppFog account. Edited the above post to include it at the end.

Comment: My mistake... I was under the incorrect impression you needed the shebang line (e.g. #!/usr/bin/python) for your modwsgi file and that your error was some weird interaction where the other interpreter (e.g. bash) was doing something unexpected.

Comment: Looks like it can't find `bottle`. Ensure it's on the system Python path.

Comment: @luminous I did an install and added bottle to my local. Apparently my AppFog server already had it natively. I'm not sure how to add it to the system python path. I added the terminal output from the install above.

Comment: For the sake of hello world, I would suggest commenting out the first line (change import bottle to #import bottle).  Going slightly further, if you run python and do an import bottle, does that work?

Comment: @Foon commenting out bottle did work! However, what IS bottle? Is this something I need to get working for future scripts?

Comment: bottle is one of many libraries for doing Python web development (see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bottle/0.11.6).  So, yes, if you want to use bottle, you will need to get working for future scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (or possibly switch WebServer to webserver (what I changed was make the pathnames all be WebServer; you had some Webserver (lowercase S) and some WebServer

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
          DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/python-mn"
          ServerName python.local
          ServerAlias www.python.local
          WSGIScriptAlias / /Library/WebServer/Documents/python-mn/wsgi.py
          <Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/python-mn>
                #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
          </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Per [Apple's mod_hfs_guide](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA21099), your error message is due to Apple trying to protect you from someone taking advantage of HFS being case-insenstive to access something that should be protected by using a funny cased version of the name.

Comment: I'm getting a new error message now. I pasted the message and error log above. It seems it can't find "bottle."  I'm confused since this works fine on my AppFog app.

Answer (score 0):

I see you figured it out, but for future reference...

It looks like `bottle` is not part of your Python system path. To add it to your path, you have two options:

1. Add `bottle` to your system Python path manually by downloading it here:

   https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bottle/0.11.6

   Once downloaded, run:

   ```
   tar xvf bottle-0.11.6.tar.gz
   cd bottle-0.11.6/
   sudo python setup.py install
   ```
2. Use a package manager to pull it for you. You can install pip (you can also use easy_install, brew, or macports) from here:

   https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/1.4.1

   And then, once installed (similar to above), run:

   ```
   pip install bottle
   ```

Comment: I went through your steps and everything appears to have installed correctly. I had to install pip as well (I followed these instructions http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html). I'm still getting the 500 Internal Server error. I tried restarting apache as well, still no luck.

Comment: I am getting a brew doctor Warning message now. Not sure it has anything to do with it though: "Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

    /Users/michele/.rbenv/shims/passenger-config"

Comment: Yeah, you probably should have done one or the other, not both. Is the error you're getting from Apache still the same? Still missing bottle?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. If you run `python -c 'import bottle'` in your systems terminal, does it throw any errors?

Comment: There weren't any errors with that command in terminal or the apache error log.